# Why is Net::SSH2::File only allowing 32500 bytes on a write?

Tags: perl, sftp

I have a Redhat 5.5 Linux machine using Perl Net::SSH2 to sftp a file. It appears that once the filehandle is opened for writing, I can only write a maximum buffer length of 32500 bytes for each call to $fh->write($buffer). I've had to limit my file read to 30*1024 bytes before writing it to the Net::SSH2::File filehandle. Shouldn't I be able to write a larger buffer? The filesize I am copying is about 800k. The buffer I am talking about is the size of the write chunk. I can continually write this chunk size.

Comment: Do you mean that you can write at most ~32K bytes at a time? Or that after a total of ~32K bytes (say, write 1K bytes 32 times), the program hangs?

Comment: Yes, 32500 bytes per write. Gabriel Ross hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 4):

It's apparently a hard-coded limit in Net::SSH2. See here:

http://www.libssh2.org/mail/libssh2-devel-archive-2010-06/0104.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Most SSH **servers** limit the size of the packets they can handle to some size around 32Kb and so clients do the same for interoperability.

You can use [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign), that doesn't have that limitation (its buffers will grow to accommodate data of any length as far as memory is available) and it can run on top of Net::SSH2 via the Net_SSH2 backend [Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Net_SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign%3a%3aBackend%3a%3aNet_SSH2) or just use the OpenSSH binary client.